# Custom HTML option not working in Mailchimp with a href intent

Tags: html, android-intent, href, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Mailchimp has a feature that allows you to enter custom HTML to a template. The custom HTML I am adding is an a href link that when clicked opens a chat with a specific user on Whatsapp. Example of code below:

`<a href="intent://send/123456677888#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">Click here for Whatsapp</a>`

'123456677888' being your Whatsapp phone number with country code.

The problem is that when I preview the template with the customized HTML, the a href link only shows up as text and is not functioning as a hotlink.

I have tested this same code on my webpage and it works perfectly, with exception to iPhones as the code only works with Android phones with Whatsapp.

I have read Mailchimp's KB articles on HTML and they state that there are some limitations on JS, but it doesn't mention anything specific to the code I am using.

I would love to contact Mailchimp to find out if what I am attempting is possible, but they only offer paid technical support, which is not something I can afford at the moment.

Appreciate any insights any of you might have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the opening is something like that:

```
whatsapp://send?text=
```

applied to your case:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send/123456677888#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">Click here for Whatsapp</a>
```

if you need more info:

[Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012)

[IOS](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/es/iphone/23559013)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. When I make the changes to the a href with whatsapp://send/ it gives the same result as before with the link not active and only listed as text when tested in the preview of mailchimp.

Comment: It should be working but only from the android browser, try starting with basic arguments.

Comment: I already did and it works launching the whatsapp app with no problem from phone with no problem at all using a custom embedded form, just adding. <a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello">Click here for Whatsapp</a> in the html.